# HTACCESS rewriting not working for more than 2 parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Alright. Here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bank.php?bank=$1
#This will make my url e.g. site.com/citibank

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ state.php?bank=$1&state=$2
#This will make my url e.g. site.com/citibank/new-york

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ location.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3
#This will make my url e.g. site.com/citibank/midtown
```

PROBLEM: Its working till second rule but when it comes to third and final rule, it created url like: site.com/bank.php/citibank/new-york

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your first rule is using `.*` pattern and is matching everything. Change your code to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ bank.php?bank=$1 [L,QSA]
#This will make my url e.g. site.com/citibank

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ state.php?bank=$1&state=$2 [L,QSA]
#This will make my url e.g. site.com/citibank/new-york

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ location.php?bank=$1&state=$2&district=$3 [L,QSA]
#This will make my url e.g. site.com/citibank/midtown
```

Comment: site says: ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: Thank you so much Anubhava. That was quick an exact :) One more thing I would like to clarify, Is: 
site.com/citibank and site.com/citibank/ make any difference?

Comment: No they both will be handled by first rule.